# CSS Scrollbar in seamless layout - combining 3 divs into 1 bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and I also googled, did some research but didn't find any answer. I try to explain the best I can:

I made a layout that has a fixed navigation bar on the top, then comes a banner, the main content and the footer. Usually there is no problem to achieve this, but I made the layout seamless (no border around the divs).

I only want one scrollbar on the side. If that one gets used it should move the banner, content and footer. The navigation bar should stay on top. With the code I wrote I have currently 3 bars showing. :( Those 3 bars I want to combine into a single scroll bar.

Any help would be greatly appriciated, because this is giving me headaches. :-D

Here is the code:

```css
body {
 background-color: #f0e2c8;
}
#header
{
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-image: url(menubg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: top;
 height: 85px;
 width: 100%;

}
#banner
{
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 overflow: scroll;
 z-index: -1;
}
#content
{
 position:fixed;
 top:470px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 background-image: url(spacerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: top;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
}
#footer
{
 position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 background-image: url(footerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: top;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
 
  <div align="center"> <img src="layout/menu.png" alt="" width="876" height="48" border="0" usemap="#Map" /> 
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="1,14,73,50" href="#" target="_self" alt="" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="125,14,245,50" href="#" target="_self" alt="" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="300,14,464,50" href="#" target="_self" alt="" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="525,14,724,50" href="#" target="_self" alt="" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="780,14,911,50" href="#" target="_self" alt="" />
    </map>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="banner">
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <div align="center"><img src="layout/banner.png" alt="" width="1200" height="430" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>adfafadf</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>adfafdsf</p>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

 
 
</body>
```

Comment: If I make the content relative without a height it doesn't show the entire banner and the background of the layout (it's a picture). It cuts away some of the height. And the banner picture doesn't resize anymore as well. :(